# onchange event not triggered on removal of last character - LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, onchange

I need to display the count/length of string entered in a text box as and when changed(addition/subtraction of new characters) using LWC

```
   <template>
           <lightning-input 
                type="text" 
                name="test" 
                label="test" 
                value ={testAttr}
                maxlength = "80"
                onchange = {handleChange}>
            </lightning-input>
            <span>{testAttr.length} characters</span>
    </<template>

    @track testAttr='';
    handleChange(event){
       let value = event.target.value;
       this.testAttr = value;
    }
```

Unfortunately, this code doesn't track the removal of last character or selecting whole string at once and deleting/removing.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Assuming your tracked variable is of course in the Controller and not Template it could be helpful to share a repo case on playground.

Your shared Code on a playground works fine:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/EU2p8FGBX/1/edit

Behaves exactly like you expect it to do

Comment: You  are right, it is working. Not sure if there was some caching issue with the browser.

Comment: ya could be - i rarely also getting older versions of my component during development

Comment: The repro on playground shows that this works, can someone post this as an answer?